# WebdriverAgent: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Tags: ios, mobile, appium, appium-ios

I am trying to build webdriveragent onto the iOS real device. It was working fine till yesterday. I haven't made any updates to the box since then. I see the below error while compiling:

\Ld /Users/qaautomation/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/WebDriverAgentLib.framework/WebDriverAgentLib normal arm64 (in target: WebDriverAgentLib)
    cd /usr/local/lib/node_modules/appium/node_modules/appium-xcuitest-driver/WebDriverAgent
    export IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET=11.3
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang -arch arm64 -dynamiclib -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS12.0.sdk -L/Users/qaautomation/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos -F/Users/qaautomation/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos -F/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/Library/Frameworks -F/usr/local/lib/node_modules/appium/node_modules/appium-xcuitest-driver/WebDriverAgent/Carthage/Build/iOS -F/usr/local/lib/node_modules/appium/node_modules/appium-xcuitest-driver/WebDriverAgent/Carthage/Build/Mac -filelist /Users/qaautomation/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Build/Intermediates.noindex/WebDriverAgent.build/Debug-iphoneos/WebDriverAgentLib.build/Objects-normal/arm64/WebDriverAgentLib.LinkFileList -install_name @rpath/WebDriverAgentLib.framework/WebDriverAgentLib -Xlinker -rpath -Xlinker @executable_path/Frameworks -Xlinker -rpath -Xlinker @loader_path/Frameworks -miphoneos-version-min=11.3 -dead_strip -Xlinker -object_path_lto -Xlinker /Users/qaautomation/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Build/Intermediates.noindex/WebDriverAgent.build/Debug-iphoneos/WebDriverAgentLib.build/Objects-normal/arm64/WebDriverAgentLib_lto.o -Xlinker -export_dynamic -Xlinker -no_deduplicate -fobjc-arc -fobjc-link-runtime -lxml2 -framework RoutingHTTPServer -framework YYCache -compatibility_version 1 -current_version 1 -Xlinker -dependency_info -Xlinker /Users/qaautomation/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Build/Intermediates.noindex/WebDriverAgent.build/Debug-iphoneos/WebDriverAgentLib.build/Objects-normal/arm64/WebDriverAgentLib_dependency_info.dat -o /Users/qaautomation/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/WebDriverAgentLib.framework/WebDriverAgentLib

Undefined symbols for architecture arm64:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_XCElementSnapshot", referenced from:
      l_OBJC_$_CATEGORY_XCElementSnapshot_$_FBIsVisible in XCUIElement+FBIsVisible.o
      l_OBJC_$_CATEGORY_XCElementSnapshot_$_FBUID in XCUIElement+FBUID.o
      l_OBJC_$_CATEGORY_XCElementSnapshot_$_WebDriverAttributes in XCUIElement+FBWebDriverAttributes.o
      objc-class-ref in XCUIElement+FBWebDriverAttributes.o
      objc-class-ref in XCUIElement+FBUtilities.o
      l_OBJC_$_CATEGORY_XCElementSnapshot_$_FBAccessibility in XCUIElement+FBAccessibility.o
      l_OBJC_$_CATEGORY_XCElementSnapshot_$_FBScrolling in XCUIElement+FBScrolling.o
      ...
**ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture arm64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)**

Am using latest Xcode and appium
Could someone help me resolve this?

Answer (score 1):

Add -Wl,-U,"_OBJC_CLASS_$_XCElementSnapshot" in other linker flags in WebDriverAgentLib target.